# Как добавить анимацию в модель с помощью Unity 3D?

Tags: unity3d

Допустим, есть две модели с mixamo.com, они одинаковы за исключением анимации. Можно ли объединить их в одной модели таким образом, чтобы модель содержала в себе две анимации?

[image: Модели с разными анимациями]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто попробуйте сохранить сами **анимации**.

Затем используйте их в нужной вами модели в **Animator**, так можно сделать с любой модели схожим скелетом

Можете нажать на анимацию и использовать комбинацию клавиш **Ctrl+D**

[image: Вот они]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QabYO.png
Я добавил анимации в контроллер и его в свою очередь в Animator. Так ли это должно выглядеть? Если да, то как запускать ту или иную анимацию?

Comment: @JohnJemon, Вы сделали правильно, теперь можете использовать **стрелки** от **Entry** до вашей анимации в Вашем случае. 

И управлять переходами по переменным. Но это я думаю тема для другого вопроса. Я оставлю ссылку на материал где Вы сможете ознакомиться с анимациями [Видео урок вот тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkaysu1Z-N8&t=365s)
А если я ответил на Ваш основной вопрос то попрошу отметить его как правильный.